# Unix fails to load external entity when New line in text file

Tags: xml, shell, unix

I am using UNIX C Shell.

**My Requirement:**
Read multiple XML files from R Drive (different from working directory) and put them in a output file.
The filepaths of the above XML files are written in a notepad txt file (exp.txt) which is placed in my working directory.

Current exp.txt content (single XML file path):

```
/mnt/FusionOATSResults/REEResults/19Jul2016/dtegroup/7899464/152877508_1/Session1/BasicReport.htm_source.xml
```

Current working command:

```
foreach xmlfile ( "`cat exp.txt`" )
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//RESULT_STEP' -v '@time_stamp' -o '|' -v '@step_name' --nl "$xmlfile" >> /scratch/ryerrams/view_storage/outputFile.txt
end
```

The above command works perfectly.

But, when I add a newline in the exp.txt file to read the second xml file also, it fails.

New 'exp.txt' content:

```
/mnt/FusionOATSResults/REEResults/19Jul2016/dtegroup/7899464/152877508_1/Session1/BasicReport.htm_source.xml
/mnt/FusionOATSResults/REEResults/19Jul2016/dtegroup/7899464/152877536_1/Session1/BasicReport.htm_source.xml
```

Current command:

```
foreach xmlfile ( "`cat exp.txt`" )
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//RESULT_STEP' -v '@time_stamp' -o '|' -v '@step_name' --nl "$xmlfile" >> /scratch/ryerrams/view_storage/outputFile.txt
end
```

I get the below error message:

```
failed to load external entity `"/mnt/FusionOATSResults/REEResults/19Jul2016/dtegroup/7899464/152877508_1/Session1/BasicReport.htm_so"rce.xml`
```

What am I missing? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: `dos2unix exp.txt` will convert `\r\n` line endings to unix-standard `\n` line-endings. This causes problems for people all the time. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shellter. This worked.